# Array objects from json file displaying on dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display the numbers from a json file to display the select dropdown options one by one. This is the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbfhT7LOiT4QKAl13KBy?p=preview)

I am getting the options in a row as assigned but I need them one by one. Please correct me.

Json file:

```
{

"numDetails" : [

                         {

                           "code" : "ABC",

                           "num" : ["246810","4681012","681012"]},

                         {   
                           "code" : "DEF",

                           "num" : ["13579","357913","5791315"]}

                       ]

}
```

Comment: could you explain the output you want? do you want to have 6 elements in the select?

Comment: yes six elements one by one not like two row option

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array with all option in your controller and use it with ng-options , try the following code:

In your controller:

```
        for(var j = 0;j < jsonArray.length;j++){
               for(var i=0;i< jsonArray.num.length;i++){
                        $scope.myArray.push(jsonArray[j].num[i];
                }
        }
```

In your select:

```
      <select ng-options="row in myArray"></select>
```

Comment: Hi Carton Thanks for your response ,but its not working for me is this select tag correct <select  data-ng-options="row in myArray" id="Number" data-ng-model ="numCode" class="form-control input-sm" ></select>

Comment: Why do you use ng-data-option ? Oh i missed a s at ng-options , edited my answer it should works now